# uniqueness of mathematical induction

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have some problem with the theory of mathematical induction.

Suppose I have a recursive formulae; I assumed a function and I proved it by induction that it satisfying the recursion.

But does it imply that the function is the only one satisfying the recursion?

---

[Updated.]

> [image]

Here we are assuming $a_n= \cot{\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}}$. But is it the only one satisfying the relation?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you "proved it by induction" then any two functions agree at $1$, at $2$ and so on forever. If this doesn't convince you, please edit the question to show specific example with a recursion and induction and your proof, and then what you're worried about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks sufficient details to answer specifically. In general, induction does not guarantee uniqueness, but there are cases when you can prove that the solution is unique.

Which one your specific case is depends on the recursion and what you managed to prove exactly.

For example, consider $a_n = a_{n-1}$ with $a_0=k$ for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$. If you use induction to prove $a_n \equiv k \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ then it is easy to see this solution is unique.

On the other hand, consider $a_n - 3a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2}=0$ with no initial conditions specified. Then you have 2 solution families $a_n \equiv k$ and $a_n = c \cdot 2^n$ which will both satisfy the recurrence, so if you prove $k$ satisfies it, or if you prove $c \cdot 2^n$ satisfies it, neither will guarantee uniqueness.

**UPDATE**

For your specific problem, since the initial conditions are specified, there is only one sequence that satisfies the recurrence. This is easy to see by repeatedly plugging in the previous value to get the next one, starting with the initial condition.

How you express that sequence may be different, i.e. $a_n = (-1)^n$ can also be expressed as $a_n = \sin(n \pi)$, but it cannot change what the actual values of the sequence are. Hence, if there is any one representation which makes it convenient to take the limit, you could use it.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1582458_limit_of_a_sequence check here we assuming $a_n= \cot{\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}}$ but is it the only function satisfying the relation? I have doubt

Comment: @SoumyadiptaDas see the update

Comment: thanks understand